# How to round binary fractions correctly

Tags: numerical-methods, computer-science, binary, number-systems

We have three fractions which are converted to binary fractions

$$x= \frac{3}{5} ,\ y=\frac{4}{7} ,\ z=\frac{1}{35} $$

$$x_{binary}=0.\overline{1001}$$
$$y_{binary}=0.\overline{100}$$
$$z_{binary}=0.\overline{000001110101}$$

The binary fractions have to be rounded at the 5th bit. The 5th bit from $x_{binary}$ is 1. Do we get $0.\overline{1011}$ as the result? The 5th bit from $y_{binary}$ is also 1. Do we get $0.\overline{101}$ as the result? What about $z_{binary}$ the 5th bit is a 0, so will the number remain the same as before? Rounding in the binary system is quite confusing to me.

Answer (score 4):

Rounding is exactly the same as in decimal. If you want the conventional rounding (rounding from halfway up) in binary, it's actually even easier: if the next digit is 0, just cut off, if next digit is 1, increment the last bit (and carry if necessary). But you *have* to drop the repetition! Once you round, you get a finite binary expansion:

To 5 places (no carry, next bit is 0)
$$x_\text{binary}=0.1001100110011001...\approx 0.10011$$
To 4 places (carry one, flips the 4th place up, as it was already 1, carries to 3rd place)
$$x_\text{binary}=0.1001100110011001...\approx 0.1010$$